# Unexpected WordPress search results

Tags: ajax, search

I'm making a simple project management plugin. I want to have a AJAX powered search feature for the projects. I have it working kind of.

It just a simple search form.

```
<form id="ppw__project-search" class="ppw__project-search" method="get" action="">
    <div class="ppw__th">
        <label for="ppw__project-search-submit"><?php echo _e( 'Project Search', PPW_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="ppw__td">
        <div class="ppw_searchfrom__input">
            <input type="search" value="" class="ppw__project-search-field" name="ppw__project-search" id="ppw__project-search-field" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="ppw__project-search-submit" class="ppw__project-search-submit" value="<?php echo _e( 'Submit', PPW_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

With the JavaScript

```
$('#ppw__project-search-submit').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // clear the field
    $('#ppw__project_ac_results').html('');
    var search_value = $('#ppw__project-search-field').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ppw_project_vars.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'ppw_project_search',
            search_string: search_value,
            ppw_search_nonce: ppw_project_vars.ppw_project_search_nonce
        },
        success: function(search_response) {
            $('#ppw__project-display-results').html('');
            if(search_response.search_id === 'found') {
                $(search_response.search_results).appendTo('#ppw__project-display-results');
            } else if(search_response.search_id === 'fail' ) {
                $('#ppw__project-display-results').text(search_response.search_msg);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); 
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
    });

});
```

This is the class with the methods for the AJAX request

```
if( !class_exists( 'PPW_Project_Search_Filter' ) ) {
    class PPW_Project_Search_Filter {

        /**
         * Initialize the class
         *
         * @since 0.0.1
         */
        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_ppw_project_search', array( $this, 'search' ) );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ppw_project_search', array( $this, 'search' ) );
        } // end __construct

        /**
         * Results
         *
         * Return the AJAX results
         *
         * @since      0.0.1
         * @global     obj $wp_query the wordpress query obj
         * @return     void
         */
        public function search() {
            global $wpdb;
            if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ppw_search_nonce'], 'ppw_project_search_nonce') ) {
                $search_query   = trim( $_POST['search_string'] );
                $options        = get_option( PPW_PREFIX . '_options' );
                $excerpt_length = $options[PPW_PREFIX . '_options_project_excertp_length'];
                if( $search_query ) {
                    $found_projects = get_posts( array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 9999,
                        'post_type'      => 'ppw_projects',
                        's'              => $search_query
                    ) );
                    foreach( $found_projects as $project ) {
                        $project_description = get_post_meta( $project->ID, PPW_PREFIX . '_projects_desc', true );
                        $project_category    = get_post_meta( $project->ID, PPW_PREFIX . '_projects_category', true );
                        $project_clients     = get_post_meta( $project->ID, PPW_PREFIX . '_projects_client', true );
                        $project_assigned    = get_post_meta( $project->ID, PPW_PREFIX . '_assigned', true );
                        $this_letter         = strtoupper( substr( $project->post_title, 0, 1) );
                        $curr_letter         = '';
                        $project_results     = 'a';
                        if( $this_letter != $curr_letter ) {
                            $curr_letter = $this_letter;
                            $project_results .= '<div class="ppw__Listing-group--title"><h2>' . $this_letter . '</h2></div>';
                        }
                        $project_results .= '<div class="ppw__project-display--entry">';
                            $project_results .= '<h2 class="ppw__project-name">';
                                $project_results .= $project->post_title;
                            $project_results .= '</h2>';
                            $project_results .= '<div class="ppw__categories">';
                                $project_results .= ppw_get_product_categories($project->ID);
                            $project_results .= '</div>';
                            $project_results .= '<div class="ppw__project-description">';
                                $project_results .= wp_trim_words( $project_description, $excerpt_length );
                            $project_results .= '</div>';
                            $project_results .= '<div class="ppw__user-avatars">';
                                $project_results .= ppw_get_project_user_avatar( $project_clients, $project_assigned );
                            $project_results .= '</div>';
                            $project_results .= '<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="ppw__products--link"></a>';
                        $project_results .= '</div>';
                    }
                    echo json_encode( array( 'search_results' => $project_results, 'search_id' => 'found' ) );
                } else {
                    echo json_encode( array( 'search_msg' => __('No Projects Found', PPW_TEXTDOMAIN ), 'search_results' => 'none', 'search_id' => 'fail' ) );
                }
            }
            die();
        } // end results
    }
} // end PPW_Project_Search_Filter
```

This kind of works.

Let say I have four projects titled

```
Project 1
Project 2
A Project
B Project
```

If I search for *Project 1* or *Project 2*. I get the expected result.

Now, whats happening is when I search for *A Project* or *B Project*. The only result I get is *Project 1*.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this just the bad default WordPress search doing it's thing?

Comment: Show the php hooked to 'ppw_project_search'

Comment: There's no hook, it's just a form.

Comment: Never mind I see what your getting at. I added the hook.

Comment: Arg, no lover here.